# Syntax error while using psycopg2 to insert/update record

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

```
record_insert = """ INSERT INTO geo_index   
    (   link_id,
        tile_id,
        geo_index) VALUES (%s,%s,%s""" + ")" + \
        """ON CONFLICT (link_id, tile_id)
        DO UPDATE
        link_id = {},
        tile_id = {},
        geo_index = {} """.format(link, tile, geo_index)
```

EDIT:
my code:
record_insert = """ INSERT INTO geo_index
(   link_id,
tile_id,
geo_index) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)
ON CONFLICT (link_id, tile_id)
DO UPDATE
link_id = {},
tile_id = {},
geo_index = {} """.format(link, tile, geo_index)
print(record_insert)
record_to_insert = (link, tile, geo_index)

```
cur.execute(record_insert,record_to_insert)
```

Comment: You should show the error output that you received. Was it a Python syntax error or a PostgreSQL syntax error? Show the exact stack trace!

Comment: Also, please use ``` to format blocks of code. Makes it much easier to read your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems here. The big one is that you are open to an SQL injection attack. Never, never, NEVER construct SQL queries by putting untrusted strings into SQL code. See:

- https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection
- https://xkcd.com/327/

To avoid SQL injection attacks, use the right way of building an SQL command. With psycopg2, that means something like

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""
INSERT INTO geo_index ( link_id, tile_id, geo_index) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)
ON CONFLICT (link_id, tile_id)
DO UPDATE SET link_id = %s, tile_id = %s, geo_index = %s
""",
link, tile, geo_index, link, tile, geo_index)
```

See https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries for the docs.

Your second problem is that you are trying to combine two different styles of string formatting: the `%` operator versus `.format()`. `%s` and the `%` operator have been in Python forever, so you will see lots of existing code and libraries that use them. `{..}` and the `.format()` method are more recent, thus not as widely used. Trying to mix and match really will not work.

Your third problem is that you are trying to interpolate 3 values into a string that takes 6. That is a quirk of using PostgreSQL's "on conflict update" feature: you need to specify the 3 values to insert, and then you need to specify them again in case there is a conflict on insert.

I am deliberately NOT showing you how to construct this string with manual `%` or `.format()` calls, because either one leaves you with an SQL injection attack. Use psycopg2's way of formatting your query, and you won't have that problem.

Comment: When I try this I get an error : psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "link_id"
LINE 3: ...         ON CONFLICT (link_id, tile_id) DO UPDATE link_id = ...

Comment: I have realised my mistake I was missing the SET

Comment: You left out the canonical reference to SQL Injection, [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/327/) ;-)    Good old little Bobby Tables.